# CucumberException Error parsing feature file stepdefile/dailyroutine.feature

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

This is just a proof of concept:

but I am getting lexing error on the 10th line

feature file:

```
Feature: Attitude Matter  

In order to know Attitude  
As a working guy   
I want to know whom to greet  

@tester  
Scenario: Employee and his attitude  

Given I work day-shifts    <<<<<<<10th line  
When I meet newspaperman  
Then I greet paperman  

Given I work latenights  
When I meet watchman  
Then I greet watchman
```

Comment: just a guess: could it be the hyphen being interpreted as a minus?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What does your step definition look like? when I try ```Given(/^I work day\-shifts$/) do``` to start the step definition, it works fine.